# How to keep connection up and running, even when the application is closed (How do messaging applications like Whatsapp implement this?)?

Tags: android, push-notification

I want to receive notifications on my android application and for that i need a connection between the server and android. I have written this code in an Activity which calls a Service. I am receiving notifications as long as the Application is running and even if it in running in the Background.

But once I manually close the application I don't receive the notifications.

I have also tried to use a BroadcastReceiver to call the Service using the following code:

```
Intent myAlarm = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent recurringAlarm = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, myAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
alarms.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, updateTime.getTimeInMillis(), 500, recurringAlarm);
```

and the AlarmReceiver code is:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent myService = new Intent(context, MqttMessageService.class);
    context.startService(myService);
}
}
```

But even then the same problem occurs. Since every messaging application uses notification I think I am missing something of how to do this.

Comment: Generally, they will be using Firebase Cloud Messaging, at least on Google Play ecosystem devices.

Comment: Like CommonsWare says, WhatsApp & others will use "Push based architecture" https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging